# Join Multiple result tables into permanent

Tags: sql-server

I have a number of queries that are run at the same time but now I want the result to populate a permanent table that I've created.

Each of the queries will have a column called 'Descript' which is what I want all the results to join to so i want to make sure that if the Descript column is out of order (or null) on one of the queries it will link the figures to the correct Descript.

I performed an INTO after the end of each query being run but this didn't work.
The first level of data went in but the second level just went underneath the first (if that makes sense) creating more rows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.RESULTTABLE (Descript, Category, DescriptCount)

SELECT Descript, Category, DescriptCount

FROM @Query1
```

[image: Example data and result]

I have around 15 queries to join into 1 table so any help to understand the logic is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do not you join query1 and query2 `ON query1.Descript = query2.Descript` ?

Comment: Each query is an individual query that is triggered by various criteria. Depending on the criteria it will populate a certain table. I was able to create the correct result by combining all the queries into temp tables but I need to get it when 1 is run it will populate that specific part of the permanent table.  Its possible I'm drastically over complicating this

Comment: So, you want to UPDATE the record if it already exist ? Is Descript a PK of the `RESULTTABLE` table ?

Comment: I'll clear the contents of the table then load the new data. For this purpose the descript is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question clearly, you want to insert query results which is not stored in the `Temptable` and update already existing records in the table.

```
update R set Category = Q.Category, DescriptCount = Q.DescriptCount,
from #ResultTable R inner join @Query1 Q ON R.Descript = Q.Descript

INSERT INTO dbo.RESULTTABLE (Descript, Category, DescriptCount)
SELECT Descript, Category, DescriptCount FROM @Query1 where Descript NOT IN (select Descript from #ResultTable)
```

Then you can process the same approach for other queries.

Comment: Hi, This basically worked. I realised that the update wasn't working because the table hadn't been populated with any values. Once i'd got data in there I managed to sort it out (although i ended up using a  different to organise the data to the way i specified in my question) your response allowed me to solve my issue. Thanks  lot